# change minimize effect in C#

Tags: c#, winapi, minimize

I'm trying to change the default windows minimize effect with a C# winforms app.
I have no idea where to start.
Maybe I should set some kind of hook or something?
I just need to know, when a window likes to be minimized, the minimizing itself is no problem.
Anyone having any ideas??

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

You can set certain properties on the actual properties of the form.

Comment: @Datoon: He is trying to get notified by the operating system when any window in any application is minimized.

Comment: yes, I'm trying to get notifyed WHEN a window is about to be minimized, WHICH window is about to be minimized, and to ABORT the procedure, so I can minimie it myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This CodeProject article shows how to create a Global System Hook in .NET.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/globalsystemhook.aspx

Basically what you will want is this:

http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/241866-capturing-onminimize-event

Except using a global system hook.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SetWindowsHookEx to set a WH_CALLWNDPROC hook I think you will get the SC_MINIMIZE message.

Also take a look at [this code project post to see if it has what you need](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/MinimizedAnyWindowToTray.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following library to detect when a windows is being minimized: [Using Window Messages to Implement Global System Hooks in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/WilsonSystemGlobalHooks.aspx)